# Unsure about tic_tac_toe changing board

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tic-tac-toe

I am programming a Tic-Tac-Toe game in Python 3. I have made the boards as 2D arrays, and have functions for printing the board as a grid, a tutorial, and taking and putting input.

It has the bare-bones abilities to properly display the boards, and process the inputs, along with processing, but I have two major issues in my algorithms. They are:

1. Detecting whether a win has occurred. (afterward, It should ask the players if they want to play again, and acting accordingly.)
   2.(Optional, but appreciated)How to create a CPU to play with a single player.

I have some rough concept of using a "for loop" for the turn switch and game-win mechanics, but the game could break in the event of a tie if that is not implemented.

If anyone has any solution for the following problems or general suggestions,
please post them here.

```
    from array import *
    class board:
        def __init__(self, row_1, row_2, row_3):
            self.row_1 = row_1
            self.row_2 = row_2
            self.row_3 = row_3
            # full_board is two-dimensional array
            self.full_board = row_1, row_2, row_3
    dash = "-"
    main_board = board([dash, dash, dash], [dash, dash, dash], [dash, dash, 
    dash,])
    def board_print(board):
        for row in board:
            for item in row:
                print(item, end = " ")
            print()

    def take_input():
        player = input("What space would you like to mark?(From 1 through 9):")
        input_process(player)

# Algorithm for player input
# Make a dictionary of player inputs as keys, and 2d array coordinates as values
# if player's input equals a dictionary value:
#   take the string and split it at ":"
#   assign the two numbers of the 2d dictionary value as part_1 and part_2
#   change the value of the matching coordinate to a "X" or "O", on the player(sorry, I can't make good CPU.)
# else:
#   print a notification that their input was invalid and recall the function
def input_process(pl_choice):
    possible_inputs = {"1" : "0:0", "2" : "0:1", "3" : "0:2", "4" : "1:0", "5" : "1:1", "6" : "1:2", "7": "2:0", "8" : "2:1", "9" : "2:2"}
    if pl_choice in possible_inputs:
        confirm = input("Are you sure you want to select %s? y/n: "%pl_choice)
        if confirm == "y":
            choice = possible_inputs[pl_choice].split(":")
            answer_p1 = choice[0]
            answer_p2 = choice[1]
            choice_parts = [answer_p1, answer_p2]
        elif confirm == "n":
            print("Oh. Well you can try again.\n")
            take_input()
    elif pl_choice not in possible_inputs or not pl_choice.isdigit():
        print("Your choice was invalid. Please try again.")
        take_input()

def change_board(play_board, player_id, input_p1, input_p2):
        if player_id == 1:
            play_board[input_p1][input_p2] = "X"
        elif player_id == 2:
            play_board[input_p1][input_p2] = "O" 

def tutorial():
        print("Welcome to the Tic-Tac-Toe tutorial.\n")
        print("This version of Tic-Tac-Toe is two-player only, although CPU may be added in the future. To play, \nYou input a number, 1-9. The numbers bind like so: ")
        tutorial_board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
        print(board_print(tutorial_board))
        print("Otherwise, this plays like on paper; get 3 in a row vertically, horizontally, or diagonally before your opponent, and you win.")
        # Placeholder for main game

    def main_game():
        print("Hello, and welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe.\nWould you like to see the tutorial? y/n:")
        tutorial_needed = input
        if tutorial_needed == "y":
            tutorial()
        elif tutorial_needed == "n":
            print("Okay. Let's start!")
            game_end = False
            actual_board = main_board.full_board
            board_print(actual_board)
            take_input()
```

Comment: Damn, the code is incomplete. I didn't notice the little things I left unfinished, but feel free to fix them and use the code for yourself(with the tag "Inspired by J Boii," please) for your own copy of the game!

Comment: You may consider changing the title to something like "How to check if a win has occurred in tic-tac-toe"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Detecting whether a win has occurred.

We define a "win" for player X as a case where one of the following is True:

- One row consists of X
- One column consists of X
- the top-left to bottom-right diagonal consists of X
- the bottom-left to top-right diagonal consists of X

#### *How do we translate this into Python?*

A row is just a sub-list in your tuple (that's the types you used), so we can just write `board[row]` to get a row. To check if `any`<sub>(notice the code format)</sub> row consists of "X", we have to check that `all` its value are equal to "X". So, we can write `any(all(field == 'X' for field in row) for row in board)`.

Columns are more complicated, because we have to work with indexes. But, basically, it's just the same thing, only the other way round: `any` column with `all` fields "X":
`any(all(board[row][column] == 'X' for row in range(3)) for column in range(3))`

Diagonals: We only have one line each, so we only need one loop.
For TL->BR, both indices are equal. So, we want `all` of the fields with equal indices to be equal to "X". `all(board[i][i] == 'X' for i in range(3))`
for BL->TR, one index is `2-other_index` (**not** 3, since sequences are zero-indexed). We want that `all` fields with the two indices to be equal to "X" `all(board[i][2-i] for i in range(3))` Question: what happens if you invert `i` and `2-i`? If you don't know, let it be printed out.

You will probably want to write a `check_win(board, player)` function to do all those above for a generic `player` -- here "X" or "O", but, if you decide to include three players on a bigger board later on...

### 2. Creating <del>a CPU</del> AI:

If you really want to create a [CPU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cpu), this is the wrong place to ask.
If you want to create a (simple) [AI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence), read on. If you want it to be complex, ask a new question.

Think about what it should do:

- should it prefer some fields because of their position?
- should it try to block the opponent quickly?
- should it try to create multiple possibilities of winning or focus on one?
- should it ...?

While in this case it is probably simpler to just simulate a few turns and choose the ones with the best possibilities of winning, asking yourself the questions above and writing something that will also work with (much) bigger boards, will be very interesting.

### 3. Switch turns.

One possibility is:

You have a sequence (str, list or tuple) of the players, like so: `"XO"`and a `round_counter` variable that is always increased. You then use `PLAYERS[round_counter % len(PLAYERS)]` to get the current player. Use the modulus operator `%` to always get a valid index.

Alternative:

Use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle):

> cycle('ABCD') --> A B C D A B C D A B C D ...

This is easier (`for current_player in itertools.cycle("XO"):`), but with the first alternative you have the benefit of a number you would have to call `enumerate(itertools.cycle("XO"))` for and you limit library usage (if this code is to shown to someone, you might want to explain how it works).

### 4. How to detect a draw:

A draw occurs when `all` fields are `not` empty (in your case, `!=`dash); this is equivalent to say that there is `not` `any` field with a dash. 
See [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to flatten the board:

> `>>> # flatten a list using a listcomp with two 'for'`
>    `>>> vec = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]`
>    `>>> [num for elem in vec for num in elem]`
>    `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

-- second-last example

Comment: Thank you for your help. While I am grateful for your input, I do have to ask: do you have any advice to make the turns switch after each input? Until I can figure out this, I can't implement your advice. I'll try to figure it out myself, but if I don't update this comment in the next week or two, consider me stumped.          P.S: I didn't even know about the _italic_any_italic_ and _italic_all_italic_ functions until now. Thank you for informing me!

Comment: @JBoii I hope the edit helps you; please excuse the numerous (spelling  & grammar) errors in the first post (I didn't have time to proof-read)   -- Python if full of very useful tools people don't seem to know about - just look at the  "use [very handy function]" answers; ``enumerate`` givers you ``index, value`` in case you're wondering